# How to launch «gdbserver» in background?

Tags: shell, terminal, debugging, background-process

When I run gdbserver on a device *(like `gdbserver :2345 myapp`)*, gdbserver completely blocks the terminal. Neither adding an ampersand `&`, nor pressing <kbd>^z</kbd> makes it running in background. I also checked: it is reproducible on Kubuntu too.

I really need to use shell commands, and since [I've no idea how to execute these via gdbserver,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757055/gdbserver-execute-a-shell-commands-of-a-target) after it's running I feel myself crippled.

Comment: Can you just run the process interactively in a persistent screen session?

Comment: @Christopher I didn't got it ☹ Did you meant a launching of a process with an ampersand character?

Comment: GNU screen is terminal multiplexer.  You just run screen and inside that you can create as many shell sessions as you like and keep switching between them as you like.

Comment: @MiroslavFranc so, as I understood the «screen» is a separate application, which isn't even installed on my Kubuntu, not to mention an embedded GNU/Linux. I am afraid that if I would wish to compile this for the embedded one, I'll stuck for a long time with a dependencies. Perhaps are there a more native way to just detach «gdbserver»?

Comment: Is it resolved ? I have the same issue.

Comment: @ransh did you try the accepted answer? Judging by the ✓ mark it have worked for me back then on embedded ancient Linux-system, and — I just checked — still does now on a modern Archlinux desktop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to have worked for the OP.

```
gdbserver :2345 ls > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I think the reason for this is because when a program is daemonized it closes all the STDIO 0,1 & 2. The next IO to open will be 0. If the program tries to use 0,1 or 2 with things like printf or scanf it will be acting on the wrong IO or a closed IO. For example if it is daemon-ized the socket opens on 0 were STDIN was and if the printf is called it will be writing to a non-open FD what would cause the program to crash.

Answer (score 2):

I have never found a way to truly fork off with a shell, there are too many reasons why something will remain connected. I wrote a very small C program to fully fork off any commands you run after it.

----- daemonize.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    // int reterr;
    pid_t pid, sid;

    //Fork the Parent Process
    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    //We got a good pid, Close the Parent Process
    if (pid > 0) { exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); }

    //Change File Mask
    umask(0);

    //Create a new Signature Id for our child
    sid = setsid();
    if (sid < 0) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    //Change Directory
    //If we cant find the directory we exit with failure.
    if ((chdir("/")) < 0) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    //Close Standard File Descriptors
    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(STDERR_FILENO);

    //----------------
    //Main Process
    //----------------
    for(i=0; i < argc - 1; i++) {
        argv[i]=argv[i+1];
    }
    argv[argc-1] = '\0';
    execv(argv[0], argv);
    //reterr = execv(argv[0], argv);
    //printf("execv failed with '%s'\n", strerror(errno));

    //Close the log
    closelog ();
}
```

--- Makefile

```
CXX = gcc

# Implicit rules needed to build .o files and Metaobject stuff (_m.o)
.SUFFIXES: .c .o .h

.c.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(XTRA_INCL)   $< -o $@

OBJECTS = daemonize.o 
daemonize: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ -pipe -O2 $(OBJECTS) $(RPATH_XT)
    strip --strip-unneeded $@

clean:
    @rm -f core *.o *_m.* *.bak *.elf
```

Comment: This really cool! But alas, it did not a trick, the «gdbserver» just seems to die just after this executed, i.e. `ps -A | grep gdbserver` shows nothing.

Comment: It could be that gdbserver is trying to do IO with a FD that it is expecting to be connected to. That would also explain why & is not letting you fork it. Do you know how to use strace to see what it is doing? If you have not used strace it can be a lot to dig in to. Another thing to try is run gdbserver like you normally do and then post the results of "ls -l /proc/$(pidof gdbserver)/fd/"

Comment: [Here's the paste](http://pastebin.com/KL0SNum3). I'll try to launch it with `strace` too, but I don't know what to look for, so it is possible that I won't find anything.

Comment: Try "strace gdbserver ... 2>&1 | grep ^open"

Comment: [That's what I got](http://pastebin.com/nBG8s6DK). After this «gdbserver» just waits for a client, no more output.

Comment: What about the list of "ls -l /proc/$(pidof gdbserver)/fd/"

Comment: It is in my second comment ☺

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18422/discussion-between-linuxguru-and-hi-angel).

Answer (score 0):

A mentor of mine, Roe Peterson, always closed the IO with duplication of null to prevent anything from re-attaching to the FD. I find daemons are more stable this way.

```
daemonize()
{
        int fd1,fd2,fd3;

        signal(SIGCLD,SIG_IGN);

        if(fork()) {
                setpgid(getpid(),getpid());
                exit(0);
        }
        setpgid(0,0);

        fd1 = open("/dev/null",O_RDWR);
        fd2 = open("/dev/null",O_RDWR);
        fd3 = open("/dev/null",O_RDWR);


        close(0); dup(fd3);
        close(1); dup(fd3);
        close(2); dup(fd3);
        close(fd3);
        close(fd2);
        close(fd1);
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the `dup`s. I re-read the accepted answer, and I think you want to make 0,1,2 descriptors to have opened /dev/null, so that printf and the likes wouldn't break, right? If it's the case, you probably want `dup2`, not `dup`. It explicitly would allow you to set 0,1,2 to refer to /dev/null.